# Remove escape characters in AccessToken in Flutter

Tags: flutter, azure, authentication, access-token

I'm using this package (https://pub.dev/packages/aad_oauth) go log users in my Flutter app, and I use the token sent to authenticate users in my .Net API.

But my token is always invalid because it contains escape characters at each quotation mark in the JSON.

Is it possible to remove those characters to get a valid token ?

Here is a look of what I got :
[image]

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What you are showing is the decoded token. You basically don't use it that unless you need to read something from it. But to authenticate your api calls you have to use encoded form of the token

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove escape characters from your string you can try this:

```
String result = "your token".replaceAll(r"\'", "'");
```

Comment: I forgot to mention it, but it's a JWT token, so I don't receive it in that form, do you think it will work ?

Comment: if it is string yes, you need remove \ from your string.

Comment: what I see from your picture, you have a string, yes?@Ferenc

Comment: I have never seen anyone expecting a decoded `jwt` token for authorization, so while this does answer the question how to replace the escape characters, it does not solve your problem. Most (all?) servers expect the token to be base64 encoded and split into 3 parts.

Comment: I didn't need a decoded jwt token, but when I receive my token from my Azure AD, wherever I use it, the token is invalid, but when I decode it I saw a difference with a token provided by the Graph API : the escape characters that are in the payload @voidvoid